# Content is not including in contentEditable Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I would like to create a contentEditable tag in my page all i want is whatever the text i'm typing after i created this element should go into that tag but it's not happening like that. can someone help me out ?

```
var pElement = document.createElement('p');
$(pElement).attr('contenteditable','true')
           .addClass('current');
$(getPElement).append(pElement);
$(getPElement).find('p.current').focus();
```

Comment: That's not the way to apply an event handler, and without seeing the `editScenarioStepTitle` function, how should we know why it's not doing what you're expecting ?

Comment: Hey those are manual functions its totally different part. all i want is why my content is not going inside of p tag ?

Comment: Inside how exactly? Seems to work for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/5wK9m/

Comment: @user2646575 It works exactly as supposed: http://jsfiddle.net/xVC7E/ What is `getPEElement`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a contenteditable element with jQuery, you can do it like this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fe827/)):

```
$("<div>").attr('contenteditable', 'true').html("edit me!").appendTo('body')
```

Comment: creating like that is fine dude. But once created and made it focused whatever i type in body should go inside of newly created div